# How to set up callback URL in ZF2 from Paypal?

Tags: php, paypal, callback, zend-framework2

I am trying to use Paypal express checkout from my Zend framework (version 2.4) application. 
The callback URL is set to http://localhost/tjla/store/payment-confirm.php 
There is a function in StoreController.php called paymentConfirmAction
The child route in my module.config.php looks like:

```
            'store' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/store[/:action]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Tjla\Controller\Store',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

When the Paypal action completes it calls back with http://localhost/tjla/store/payment-confirm.php?token=xxxxxxxxxxx&PayerID=xxxxxxxxx
But this generates a 404 Page Not Found error 
What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your action is `paymentConfirmAction`, `http://localhost/tjla/store/payment-confirm?token=xxxxxxxxxxx&PayerID=xxxxxxxxx` should match your route. The `.php` does not, which is why you're currently getting a 404.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you.